# How to replicate couchdb instances behind home router firewalls?

Tags: linux, firewall, port-forwarding, couchdb

What are the options (if any) to allow replication between couchdb instances without portforwaring the couchdb port on a home router? Assuming both couchdb instances are behind home router firewalls.

Comment: do you have home routers on both ends? Have you considered a VPN of some sort between them?

Comment: Yes.Both ends have home routers.I have considered vpn but this usually needs a middle server.I need it to be totally p2p.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two different instance of couchdb, change the port number for second instance and then you can replicate the instances.

I have configured two instances of Couchdb on local domain network behind the firewall in similar way. 
You can also configure firewall rules for incoming connection for couchdb by allowing access to specific IP address (If both instance are on different machine).